# Understanding EJB Properties for remote lookup

Tags: java, ejb

I have a properties file which is used to config the ejb remote call to the server, ex: ejb:.....:

```
java.naming.factory.initial=org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory
java.naming.factory.url.pkgs=org.jboss.ejb.client.naming
java.naming.provider.url=http-remoting://localhost:4447
jboss.naming.client.ejb.context=true
endpoint.name=client-endpoint
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

This properties file is working for me but I do not really understand the function of each property. For example what is the difference between the address defined in `java.naming.provider.url` and `remote.connection.default.host` and `remote.connection.default.port` . If I leave one of these two out then it throws error. And even more interesting is that I can set the value for `java.naming.provider.url` to anything, for example `java.naming.provider.url=aaaa` and it still working. So confusing. Can anyone explain me what the difference between these properties is and what is the minimum set of properties that I need to provide to make the remote call work? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Im not shure which version of jboss/wildfly are you using:

`java.naming.provider.url` : is the name of the environment property for specifying the location of the JBoss JNDI service provider the client will use. The NamingContextFactory class uses this information to know which JBossNS server to connect to. The value of the property should be a URL string. For JBossNS the URL format was `jnp://host:port/[jndi_path]`. The `jnp:` portion of the URL is the protocol and refers to the socket/RMI based protocol used by JBoss. The jndi_path portion of the URL is an optional JNDI name relative to the root context, for example, apps or apps/tmp. Everything but the host component is optional. The following examples are equivalent because the default port value is 1099.  e.g.

```
jnp://www.jboss.org:1099/
```

The “new” implementation for the `ejb-remote-client` (Jboss/wildfly specific) uses the properties

```
remote.connection.default.host=localhost  

remote.connection.default.port = 8080
```

The minimun set should be something like this:

```
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port = 8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
```

[to check info about the old client implementation](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/The_Naming_InitialContext_Factories-The_standard_naming_context_factory.html)

[to check info about the "new" client implementation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_enterprise_application_platform/7.0/html/developing_ejb_applications/invoking_session_beans)